# Woocommerce: I restrict users from managing certain categories and products?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, restrict

I'm building a site selling ebooks and educational stuff. Has 2 supervisors should be assigned as Shop Manager however each supervisor is responsible of certain category and should not interrupt with the other supervisor.

Example: 
Product Category A,B,C,D

Supervisor 1 can manage and see Category A and B and related products but can't see C and D and related products. 
Supervisor 2 can manage and see Category C and D and related products but can't see A and B and related products.

How to restrict certain Woocommerce categories and related products by user id or role at the backend?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help

code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55202/how-to-hide-certain-categories-in-wordpress-dashboard)

hide product categories from the dashboard by their IDs (1,17) and user abilities (current_user_can('editor')).

```
/*
 * Hide Specified Categories (by ID) from Editors
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion' );

function wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion() {
    if( current_user_can('editor') )
        add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions($exclusions,$args) {
    return $exclusions . " AND ( t.term_id <> 1 )  AND ( t.term_id <> 17 )"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For backend you could use a plug-in called "white label branding" it will allow you to select which options users will be able to change etc. It can be set by user role easily.

Comment: I know this plugin however I don't think it can do the job I'm looking for. I have edited my question to better understand the concept. Thank you

Comment: Hi Michael thank you for your help I appreciate but if there's any further advice please let me know. Don't forget to check the question again, thank you so much

Comment: Isn't that possible with some kind of membership plugin? (Yes I recommend plug-ins due the fact that you'd write functions or edit core files otherwise)

Comment: Do you recommend a membership plugin because I check Woocommerce  Memberships but it didn't show product categories only post categories. I do recommend plugins due that if the customer added a new category I don't need to hook again into the function and add it manually every time.

Comment: Well, most plugins are made for a specific goal. I've once used a plug-in called "memberships pro" for a client that recommended it, and I'm not really sure but I think the plugin allowed you select different categories for a single user group.

Comment: Do you mean Paid Membership Pro? Not sure if it reads WooCommerce Categories because of them will read the default Wordpress Posts' categories as Product Categories are considered as custom taxonomy terms.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I don't have the plug-in anymore but you can read the description of the plug-in and check if they support custom taxonomy terms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I tried it also it reads only categories and no custom taxonomy terms

Comment: Oh... Hmmm I'm currently not behind a PC, but I will check for a solution tomorrow if someone else doesn't have the right answer okay?

Comment: Ok mate thanks a lot, I appreciate. Have a nice day!